# Apache 2 Forbidden Access to mounted directory via sshfs

Tags: apache2, vagrant, sshfs, ubuntu-15.04

I have following problem:

I would like to give an access for my Apache to index.html which exists on my Virtual Machine created by Vagrant. Directory is mounted by SSHFS with -o allow_other option.

Used tools and versions are:

**System**: Linux Ubuntu 15.04

**Apache**: 2.4.12

**Mount via SSHFS** with -o allow_other

Mount process is correct because directory and file are visible in my system. I can open/modify/etc them.

But when I try to open this file via Apache then I receive

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx.yyy.com Port 443

Configuration for Apache:

```
<Directory /var/www/interscape-frontend>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /var/www/interscape-frontend
```

Is it possible? If yes then how? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: No. We have resigned from Vagrant. In the end it doesn't fit well to our needs.
When I have joined the project Vagrant was used but it was an overkill. Docker fits much better to our needs. So I have forgotten above problem.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the folder/files? Who owns them?

If you `cd /var/www` and `ls -al` what words come up? See an example below.

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 (owner) (group)             277 Mar 16 00:31 build.xml
```

The left-most stuff is owner / group / all permissions. Following that, the owner and group are indicated. If apache isn't the owner (`www-data` usually), a part of the group listed, or the file does not permit all to have `rw` or `rwx`, then you may encounter the problem you've described.

You can change the owner and group with the following commands, respectively:

```
sudo chown -R (user) /path/to/directory
sudo chown -R (user):(group) /path/to/directory
```

Where the `-R` flag indicates to do it recursively (to all sub-directories).

Also, as per the [apache 2.4 upgrade guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) you can remove the following from your `*.conf`:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

As they only apply to apache 2.2 and under.

Comment: Folders www and var belongs to root. 
But folder with website /var/www/folder_with_website belongs to my user. As well as index.html. But because of some reason I can't change rights of folder_with_website (even in sudo mode)... This rights are:
drwxr-xr-x

Comment: @user2864125 could you provide more information on the "can't change rights of folder_with_website"? Do you get an error? What command are you using exactly? Do the files in the directory or subdirectories have the same permissions?